# Missing APP path global in Shells breaks some of my models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've got a problem with basic path globals when working in Shells.  For example, when loading my File model in a shell, the 'APP' constant is unavailable which causes this line:

```
$fileStorePath = APP.'/Data/FileStore/';
```

To generate the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in 
/home/cakedev/public_html/app/Model/File.php on line 15
```

Am I missing something basic here?  It's not like I'm trying to use an apache environment variable... All I need is the APP global.

Here's File.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

/**
 * File model
 *
 * Store files and retrieve them
 *
 */
class File extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'filename';
    public $actsAs = array('Logable','Error');

    private $__fileStorePath = APP.'/Data/FileStore/';

    function beforeSave($options = array()) {
      // Make sure input file exists
      if ( !file_exists($this->data['File']['inputfile']) ) {
        $this->throwError(__('File [%s] does not exist',$this->data['File']['inputfile']));
        return;
        }
        // Tack on the file info
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $this->data['File']['filename'] = basename($this->data['File']['inputfile']);
        $this->data['File']['mime'] = finfo_file($finfo, $this->data['File']['inputfile']);
        $this->data['File']['size'] = filesize($this->data['File']['inputfile']);
        $this->data['File']['uuid'] = uniqid();
    return true;
  }

    function afterSave($created) {
      if ( $created ) {
            // Move the file
            if ( !rename($this->data['File']['inputfile'],$this->__fileStorePath.$this->data['File']['uuid']) ) {
                $this->throwError(__('File [%s] could not be moved',$this->data['File']['input']),500);
                return;
            }
    }
    return true;
  }

  var $belongsTo = array(
            'User' => array('className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            )
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure line 14 of your File.php model file is properly closed? These kind of errors are usually generated by syntax errors on prior line(s).

Comment: post file.php or the code in file.php around line 15 so we can see what's up with the code.

Comment: Please, remove that smiley from the title.

Comment: Here is the contents of File.php.  Keep in mind, the model seems to work fine when called from within a Controller.  The error occurs due to the missing global constant when called within a Shell.

Comment: It would appear that the path global 'APP' is available in the actual shell itself (HelloShell.php, ect) but not in the model.

Comment: Well I'm an idiot... you can't concatenate in class definitions.  This is a PHP 'feature' not a cake bug.  Cake is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm an idiot... you can't concatenate in class definitions. This is a PHP 'feature' not a cake bug. Cake is working fine...